# RabbitMQ high latency on WAN

Tags: rabbitmq, settings, latency

We use RabbitMQ to transmit messages between applications.  When they are within a single LAN, transmission is very fast.  Unfortunately, when the applications are on different machines, connected by WAN (in VPN), there is a significant large delay. 
Is it possible to reduce it by setting options in RabbitMQ server or client (e.g. buffer sizes)? Does anyone have some experience in this field?

We use one connection with multiple channels, queues are durable and messages persistent. We set prefetch count setting to 50. There is only one consumer per queue.  We wonder whether Windows firewall may have some significance.

EDIT: We're running RabbitMQ 2.8.4 on Erlang R15B01
and on client's side:

```
> RabbitMQ version 3.4.0.0 platform .NET copyright Copyright (C)
> 2007-2014 GoPivotal, Inc. information Licensed under the MPL. See
> http://www.rabbitmq.com/ capabilities publisher_confirms: true
> exchange_exchange_bindings: true basic.nack: true
> consumer_cancel_notify: true connection.blocked: true
> authentication_failure_close: true
```

> Deliver: 4.8/s Acknowledge 4.8/s We are not making a big transfers.
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7BEs.png
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8P05.png
>
> Furthermore we are communicating PHP application with .NET app via
>   RabbitMQ at this strategy: 1. .NET application has persistent queues
>   waiting for requests from PHP 2. when PHP makes a request it makes
>   also a non-durable uniqe queue for listening for response from server.
>
> This strategy makes a lot of uniq queues for sending response to the
>   PHP app which are deleted after connsuming the message.
>
> Anyway this works very fast on same machine, and very slow on WAN

Comment: Did you check the network utilization ? if it is full you could consider to compress and aggregate the messages. what's your rate?

Comment: what is the network bandwidth, latency, utilization and quality?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot: The latency is 58 ms (pinged second machine), average network utilization was 2,6% when queue was still running